# How can I get devexpress pdfviewer bookmarks?

Tags: c#, devexpress, pdf-viewer

How can I get pdf bookmarks?

I want to access devexpress pdfviewer document bookmarks.

However, I couldn't access the document bookmarks in the devexpress pdfviewer.

```
  pdfViewer1.LoadDocument("test.pdf");
  //pdfViewer1.document?
  //pdfViewer1.bookmarks?
```

No attributes exist.

I want to access the bookmarks in the test.pdf file.

I am using C # and devexpress.

Comment: Did you try the _DevExpress_ [documentation](https://docs.devexpress.com/) ?

Comment: I couldn't find a way there.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to have a subscription that offers access to the non-visual [PdfDocumentProcessor component](https://docs.devexpress.com/OfficeFileAPI/DevExpress.Pdf.PdfDocumentProcessor).

Once you've loaded the file in a PdfDocumentProcessor instance, the collection of bookmarks will be present in the [PdfDocument.Bookmarks collection property](https://docs.devexpress.com/OfficeFileAPI/DevExpress.Pdf.PdfDocument.Bookmarks).

See the [Bookmarks](https://docs.devexpress.com/OfficeFileAPI/114957/pdf-document-api/additional-content/bookmarks) documentation for an example of how to create a Bookmark at runtime and add it to an existing Pdf document. This example follows the similar methods you would need to use to simply traverse the bookmarks contained in the document.